# Partial View is not displaying as a Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am trying to display a Partial View on a button click.

On my Index view I have:

```
<div id="partial" style="display:block">
    @Html.Partial("RenderDialog")
</div>
```

On button click the actionresult is called to do some stuff:

```
<a id="showConfirm" href="@Url.Action("RenderDialog", "Controller", new { fileName = item.FileName })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
```

the actionresult:

```
public ActionResult RenderDialog(string fileName, string style = "display: block")
{
    //some code...
    ViewBag.PartialStyle = style;
    return PartialView("RenderDialog", Model);
}
```

However instead of just displaying the Partial View as it does usually on the index screen it looks like it just returns a view rather than just rendering the view ON the index.

Comment: Your link redirects to the `RenderDialog` method. Are you wanting to update the partial view in the current `Index` view? (in which case you need to use ajax)

Comment: The reason I did it this way is because I wanted to pass fileName to the controller, and then display partial view.

Comment: if you need to display partial view inside the index view in a client side event (such as button click), you will need to use ajax to call your controller action, and render the output in a container/ target.

Comment: Which is what your doing :) Again, do you want to update the current page with the partial, or do you want to redirect to a new page (in which case, return a view, not a partial view)

Comment: I want to update the current page with the partial :)

Comment: Then you need to use ajax to all that method and update the DOM in the success callback